# Can I generate a Visual Studio Team Services personal access token using powershell?

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I know how to generate personal access tokens using the vsts web interface, but I want to speed up the process with a powershell script.

Is there a way to use powershell to generate a VSTS personal access token?

Comment: Are you planning to use the powershell script with access token in vNext build?

Comment: @Zaz did you ever figure out a way to generate a PAT on the fly?

Comment: No, you cannot generate one. you can only generate manually and it doesn't show up again. you can either revoke, refresh.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to do this. You can submit a feature request for this on [VSTS User Voice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-team-services).